# Phase trajectory must always enclose a fixed point

Tags: nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

I found this problem in strogatz nonlinear dynamics . 
The theorem says, 
A closed phase space trahectory must enclose a fixed point .

The question is asked as, is this true for phase surfaces other that plane , e.g sphere, torus ?

Now, the question seems very unclear to me . For cylindrical or spherical phase surfaces, if the exception is permissible, it must be owing to the return of phi to same point after rotating by 2pi . But in the question, strogatz asked to check this . Is the way of checking completely trial and error method or there is some intuitive way of constructing equations ?

Comment: Probably, at this point you have some baggage of examples for dynamical systems on spheres or tori or cylinder. If you know (or can picture) any counter-example to this statement, then you have answered the problem: no, for such or such surface it's not always the case, see the counter-example. Is this what you are asking or I've misunderstood your question?